# Anyone tried using Mapbox in a Hyperloop project?

Tags: appcelerator, mapbox, appcelerator-hyperloop

I'm trying to implement Mapbox into my Hyperloop project. But It's not working as I would expect it to.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong???

Process so far, I've imported the Mapbox-iOS-SDK into my AppC project via cocoa pods.

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
target 'Hyperloop-map-test' do
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK' end
```

That worked fine, and I can see it was installed in my project:

[image]

In my index.js controller I'm using the following:

```
var UIView = require('UIKit/UIView');
var mapView = require('Mapbox-iOS-SDK/Mapbox').Mapbox;

var map = new mapView().MGLMapView;
//map.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
map.setCenterCoordinate.CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7326808,-73.9843407);
map.zoomLevel = 12;
map.animated = no;

$.container.add(map);
```

I then run the project from the CLI which throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] Script Error Couldn't find module: Mapbox-iOS-SDK/Mapbox for architecture: x86_64
```

Comment: Did you have any more success with this? I am getting the following error:      [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nativeApp.app/nativeApp normal x86_64
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)

Answer (score 0):

wer are currently investigating an issue with Pods / Frameworks that include a Dash (`-`). You can track the JIRA-ticket [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20297). Thanks!